# Does my edit count increase even if someone overrides my edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have been editing few questions on Stack Overflow for formatting and spelling mistakes. But I have noticed, that after my edits, some other user also edits the same question and his name shows up as the last edited person on the question.

Since I had already edited that same question, does my edit count be +1 for such edits too and count towards my total no. of edits? Similarly for cases where my edits have been rolled back by the OP, even in that case does my edit count increase by 1?

Additionally, if I edit same question again twice, does my edit count be increased by 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If someone edits an item after you then you both have an edit count of +1.  You can click on the "edited" link and see the entire edit history, including the names of each user who made a change and the nature of the change.

I believe rollbacks would count.  However if you are going for a badge like Strunk & White, then editing a question twice would only count as 1 because the badge requires: **Edited 100 entries** as opposed to **100 edits**.